# MYSQL - Left join to gather posts and likes/comments from database tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently making a feed page with the intensions of having all posts, likes and comments on one page. I have three different tables. One containing the posts, one containing the likes and one containing the comments.

All posts can be shown and displayed correctly. The problem however comes when a post is liked by 2 or more people, it also duplicates the post 2 or more times in the feed. Below is my code:

```
$findShouts = $pdo->prepare('
SELECT f.id
     , f.username
     , f.name
     , f.text
     , f.timestamp
     , l.likesUsername
     , c.commentsUsername
     , c.commentsName
     , c.commentsText
     , c.commentsTimestamp
  FROM feed f
  LEFT 
  JOIN feedLikes l
    ON l.likesFeedID = f.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN feedComments c
    ON c.commentsFeedID = f.id 
 WHERE f.name IN (SELECT scoutingUsername 
                    FROM scout 
                   WHERE scoutedUsername =? 
                      OR scoutingUsername =?)  
 ORDER 
    BY f.timestamp DESC    
');

//execute query and variables
$findShouts->execute([$username, $username]);


if ($findShouts->rowCount() > 0)
    {    

//get the shouts for each scout
while($row = $findShouts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 



$shoutID[]              = $row['id'];
$shoutUsername[]        = $row["username"];
$shoutName[]            = $row["name"];
$shoutText[]            = $row["text"]; 
$shoutTimestamp[]       = $row["timestamp"];
$likesUsername[]        = $row['likesUsername'];
$commentsUsername[]     = $row["commentsUsername"];
$commentsName[]         = $row["commentsName"];
$commentsText[]         = $row["commentsText"]; 
$commentsTimestamp[]    = $row["commentsTimestamp"];
} 


$shoutCount = count($shoutUsername);


for($indexShout=0; $indexShout < $shoutCount; $indexShout++) {

//show post data

}
}
```

There are only 2 posts in my feed database and in feedLikes there is two likes for the first post. However, the first post is displayed twice.

If i `print $shoutUsername` I'd expect only 2 results (one for each post), however it shows 3, as the 2 likes for the first post are creating 2 of the same post.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you wan to diplay at the end? Post that have at least one like? or post with no.of likes?

Comment: You likely need some grouping, but can you please provide sample data and desired output? SQLFiddle is really helpful :)

Comment: Desired output is extremely similar to facebook. To show every post of the people the user is following (or their own) which will in turn have a like count, like button and all comments visible. So to show the post irrelevant of number of likes (can be 0 or 100)

Comment: Sorry @kchason I'm quite new to coding and only just learned what a join statement was today ha. Can you explain what you mean by grouping?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: If there are 2 likes by different users on a post and you want to display those usernames, it should be in different row. Why you want to display it in a single row?

Comment: With all of the content you're trying to pull at once, you'll need some parsing in one way or another. Otherwise, to get that detail in discrete columns, you'll have some duplication to handle. The other option is to use `GROUP_CONCAT` which isn't clean, and depends on your display goal.

Comment: @Harshil I originally tried to do a second query to find the likes on a post which would make it a lot easier. However, i was told after  the posts have run through the while statement i shouldn't use mysql again within a while statement. Hence trying to get all the information i need in one statement. I'm open to any suggestions on how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat all the data while selecting and parse it at later stage using PHP.
Not the best way to achieve the task but worth a try:

```
SELECT f.id
     , f.username
     , f.name
     , f.text
     , f.timestamp
     , Group_concat(l.likesUsername order by l.likesUsername separator ',') as likesUsername
     , Group_concat(c.commentsUsername order by c.commentsUsername separator ',') as commentsUsername
     , Group_concat(c.commentsName order by c.commentsUsername separator ',') as commentsName
     , Group_concat(c.commentsText order by c.commentsUsername separator ',') as commentsText
     , Group_oncat(c.commentsTimestamp order by c.commentsUsername separator ',') as commentsTimestamp
  FROM feed f
  LEFT 
  JOIN feedLikes l
    ON l.likesFeedID = f.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN feedComments c
    ON c.commentsFeedID = f.id 
 WHERE f.name IN (SELECT scoutingUsername 
                    FROM scout 
                   WHERE scoutedUsername =? 
                      OR scoutingUsername =?) 
Group by f.id                             // added group by 
 ORDER 
    BY f.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: i got this on your code: Warning: PDO::prepare() expects at most 2 parameters, 6 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/feed.php on line 214 so working ona  slight variation of it but still struggling ha

Comment: also Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Comment: Sorry, By mistake I added multiple commas in select query. Please remove it and try again.